# HERE Traffic incidents integration in Leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, here-api, traffic

**Background:**

I'm currently integrating HERE maps into our web-based application. I'm trying both - HERE provided Javascript API and Leaflet at the same time to find the best approach for our use-case.

While JavaScript API provided by HERE maps is OK, rendering wise `Leaflet` performs much better when using raster tiles.

**Issue:**

It would be fine by me to use raster tiles + leaflet, but our application also needs to display traffic incidents data.

Traffic incident data is provided by HERE in JSON and XML formats ([Documentation link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics/resource-parameters-incidents.html), [Example JSON](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/traffic/traffic-incidents)). They provide `[Z]/[X]/[Y]`, `quadkey`, `prox`, `bbox`, or `corridor` filters which can be used to retrieve filtered data set.

I've tried using `[Z]/[X]/[Y]` addressing with custom `L.TileLayer` implementation which loads appropriate JSON, converts it to GeoJSON and displays GeoJSON on map. However that approach is very inefficient and significant performance drop is visible.

**Question:**

Maybe anyone has already solved this issue and could share any insights on how the HERE traffic incidents could be shown on `Leaflet` map without encountering performance issues?

Comment: Some questions to clarify things for the uninitiated:  The JSON from HERE shows various `GEOLOC` fields that have `ORIGIN` and `TO` fields, which are basically `latlng`s.  Are you simply trying to render these as points, and a high number of points is causing performance issues?  Or does the data contain other shapes?  If its just points, are you dead set on rendering points individually (as opposed to clustering them or using a heatmap)?  Clarifying these things may help us understand what you're trying to do.  Sample code of your setup would also be helpful, if not crucial, for us to help.

Comment: Basically, where there is `ORIGIN` and `TO`, I just draw two markers - one at `ORIGIN` and one at `TO`. 

As the data is traffic incidents, I need to render them individually as clustering is not really a good approach to such data visualization. 

I'm aware that regular markers won't work, so I'm looking for a more efficient solution where I could render custom icons and have a popup shown on clicking the marker with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've found a solution for this task. Apparently I was on a good path, I only needed to optimize my implementation.

What I had to do to achieve appropriate performance is:

- Create custom `CircleMarker` extension which would draw custom icon on canvas
- Create JS worker which would fetch the data from a given URL, transform it to GeoJSON and return GeoJSON to it's listener
- Create custom `GridLayer` implementation, which, in `fetchTile` function, creates worker instance, passes it a link with appropriate `[Z]/[X]/[Y]` coordinates already set, adds listener, which listens for worker's `done` event and returns empty tile
- On worker's `done` event, custom `GridLayer` implementation creates `GeoJSON` layer, adds it to the dictionary with coordinates as a key and, if zoom level is still the same - adds that layer to the map
- Add `zoomend` observer on a `map`, which removes any layers that does not match current zoom level from the map

Now the map is definitely usable and works way faster than original HERE JS API.

**P.S.** Sorry, but I can't share the implementation itself due to our company policies.

Answer (score 1):

I created the following script, which works without any performance issues:

```
var fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
function loadTraffic(data) {
  fg.clearLayers();
  var d = data.TRAFFICITEMS.TRAFFICITEM.map((r) => {
    var latlngs = [];
    
    if (r.LOCATION.GEOLOC) {
      if (r.LOCATION.GEOLOC.ORIGIN) {
        latlngs.push(L.latLng(r.LOCATION.GEOLOC.ORIGIN.LATITUDE, r.LOCATION.GEOLOC.ORIGIN.LONGITUDE));
      }

      if (r.LOCATION.GEOLOC.TO) {
        if (L.Util.isArray(r.LOCATION.GEOLOC.TO)) {
          r.LOCATION.GEOLOC.TO.forEach((latlng) => {
            latlngs.push(L.latLng(latlng.LATITUDE, latlng.LONGITUDE));
          })
        } else {
          latlngs.push(L.latLng(r.LOCATION.GEOLOC.TO.LATITUDE, r.LOCATION.GEOLOC.TO.LONGITUDE));
        }
      }
    }
    var desc = r.TRAFFICITEMDESCRIPTION.find(x => x.TYPE === "short_desc").content;

    return {
      latlngs,
      desc
    }
  })
  console.log(d);

  d.forEach((road)=>{
    L.polyline(road.latlngs,{color: 'red'}).addTo(fg).bindPopup(road.desc);
  });
  map.fitBounds(fg.getBounds())
}
```

If this script is not working for you, please share your json file.

Comment: That would be OK if it were a single data set, but in this case, traffic incidents data is different for each tile in each zoom level, resulting in a very big markers set after zooming in/zooming out. Thats when the performance hit occurs. I need a way to efficiently load/unload a lot of markers.

Comment: I think all you have to do make this work is remove the previous featuregroup on every run of the function.  @Falke, can you modify the code to do that?  If you add that in, I think you'll have this spot on.  This doesn't sound too complicated

Comment: I updated the code, so that the old layers are deleted on a re-call of the function f.ex. in the `movend` event, this is called after zooming and dragging the map. But I don't know if this is what @hockeyman needs. Else @hockeyman you can use canvas markers and/or the [canvas renderer](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#canvas) of Leaflet this makes the performance also better.